# Check keys' expire times through the redis-cli

Tags: laravel, redis

I have a question about Redis caching.
I wrote some code to cache some information and it works fine, but is there a way to check what's being stored inside of it through `redis-cli`? I just want to make sure that the value gets deleted after 10 minutes.

how I store stuff:

`Cache::store('redis')->put('inventory_' . $this->user->steamid64, $items, 15);`

Comment: You are setting 15 minutes ttl, how can you expect it to be deleted after 10 minutes ?

Comment: Yea, I miss-typed that, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using laravel's `Cache` class instead of `Redis` - then you need to check for the `prefix`. By default it ships like this in config/cache.php

```
'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', 'laravel')
```

If there is a prefix(and it is `laravel`) it is going to be like this (if there is no prefix then you may discard `laravel:` from the key names)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get laravel:inventory_1
"somevalue"
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl laravel:inventory_1
(integer) 885
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

For the **"development"** purpose you may also use `monitor` command to see which commands are executed in redis. It is going to print like this;

```
127.0.0.1:6379> monitor
OK
1591091085.487083 [0 127.0.0.1:51828] "set" "myinventory_1" "myvalue" "EX" "900"
1591091091.143395 [0 127.0.0.1:51828] "get" "myinventory_1"
1591091095.280724 [0 127.0.0.1:51828] "ttl" "myinventory_1"
```

Side note: You don't need to call `store` method if your default cache driver is already redis.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the `redis-cli` and use:

- `keys *` to see list of all keys
- `TTL my_key_name` to see remaining expire time of the key

You can execute any of [Redis commands](https://redis.io/commands) inside of the redis-cli. It's good tool for development.

Comment: Why does the OP need to use `keys` ?

Comment: I checked that already, but it's empty, I don't think that cache is stored with keys.

Comment: @Ersoy the `keys` is useful to check the state of the Redis in development env. Suppose you put a wrong key. or your key already deleted... after all, it's boring to manually generating the key(with all prefixes and separators...

Comment: @AminShojaei i know what `keys` does, it is not related to meaning it is related to the purpose - you said TTL my_key_name so you know the key. Also how does `keys` prevent/help for "generating the key(with all prefixes and separators..." - if you want for "development" you may use "monitor" with `grep` to keep track of key.

Comment: Still thanks for the reply - `keys` is useful for development purpose (with the combination of `monitor`) but not for this problem. Best.

Comment: @Ersoy You are right. but it's a elementary level question, so i tried to push the asker. Also i voted up your answer at first place ;)